# Может ли система обязать участника указывать причину минусового голосования?

Tags: предложение

**Логика простая.**

Если вы голосуете **за ответ, то вы согласны с ним,** то есть вы ответили бы примерно так же. Поэтому необязательно давать объяснение по такому голосованию, хотя такое тоже случается. (Почему бы не отметить в ответе то, что вам показалось особенно важным.)

**Но когда вы голосуете против ответа**, то **какая информация** содержится в таком голосовании, если вы не указали причину? Что конкретно вы хотели сказать своим голосом? Если это серьезное нарушение грамматического или орфографического правила, то это, безусловно, **важно для форума**, поэтому желательно, чтобы вы  **поделились своими знаниями** с другими участниками. К примеру, на сайте "Большой вопрос" система спросит вас об этом в автоматическом режиме, иначе **голос просто не будет засчитан.** Можно ли применить такую же автоматическую систему у нас? Или хотя бы **рекомендовать** указание причины в общих правилах.

А может быть, вам просто не нравится тот человек, против которого вы голосуете? Тогда это вообще нарушает общее правило объективности, вежливости и доброжелательности.

И еще такой момент. На форуме  встречаются вопросы, которые не решаются с помощью конкретных правил, и тогда участникам приходится просто высказывать **своё мнение.** И вот в этом случае отрицательное голосование имеет **особый посыл:** существует только одно правильное мнение, причем оно именно моё.  Такая однозначность **вряд ли соответствует современному мышлению и уж конечно не развивает его.**

**Подобный вопрос задавался раньше,** но предлагались очень сложные решения. А этот вариант самый простой, проверенный на других сайтах,  и он не требует никакого ручного контроля со стороны модераторов.

Comment: Здравствуйте, товарищ редактор, как поживаете, рада вас видеть.  Я пока не заглядываю на форум, но надеюсь, что там всё благополучно.

Comment: Здравствуйте, Sharon. Да вот решил на Мету прошвырнуться. Хотел сначала в комментарии написать об опечатках, но вижу вас нет, решил сам. Ничё? Там вчера какое-то затишье было...

Comment: Да, ничё, конечно,  спасибо даже. А что в таком разговорном  стиле пишете?  Как будто какое-то настроение выражаете, я почему-то  очень забочусь о вашем настроении.

Answer (score 0):

Sharon, когда пользователь «минусует» сообщение, ему во всплывающем окошке показывается рекомендация дать обоснования. В Справке в общем-то говорится, что обсуждать проблемы ответа нужно всё равно, просто «минуса» недостаточно. Но это не так эксплицитно. Возможно, стоит изменить формулировку.

А запрет на голосование без пояснений, кажется, уже обсуждался. Ссылок сейчас не найду — но может, коллеги помогут.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Пожалуйста, измените формулировку. Сейчас на форуме минусы получают только неправильные ответы новых участников, а еще -  Sharon.  Я могу ошибиться, я не ангел, но неужели нельзя  просто подсказать, а не минусовать молча. Я исправлю ошибку и скажу спасибо. Другие из наших постоянных участников тоже ошибаются, но минус не получает никто.  Поэтому по каждому случаю  мне придется ставить сигнал тревоги: необоснованная минусовка (если, конечно, у меня  еще останется желание работать на форуме)..

Comment: Чтобы исправить формулировку, нужно инициировать отдельное обсуждение и предложить и обсудить варианты. Не вижу подозрительных схем голосования против ваших ответов.

Comment: Да нет никаких схем, я их тоже не вижу.  А что, обязательно схемы нужны, единичные случаи вас не интересуют? Лично мне хватило двух отдельных голосований за один день,  в то время как против других постоянных участников не голосуют вообще. И я не понимаю, что обсуждать. Пусть это будет обычным правилом поведения, что здесь не так, кому это плохо. Я обосновала свою точку зрения, поэтому при голосовании за мнение, а не за доказанную  ошибку я буду считать такое голосование необоснованным. Опять же если у меня возникнет желание это мнение высказывать.

Comment: За что минусуют новичков, тоже не понимаю. Ну не прочитал человек правила, задал неправильно вопрос. Так закройте его, и дело с концом, минусовать-то зачем? Он же гость всё-таки, вот и не придет больше.

Comment: Sharon, система отметок -- это путь разграничения качественных и некачественных сообщений. Если новичок сделал что-то, не прочитав правила, надо по возможности ему эти правила объяснить. Можно просто поставить минус, если нет времени на объяснения. Можно всё вместе. https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down. Правильным будет минус убрать, если недочеты исправятся. Принимать минусы близко к сердцу я вам в который раз не советую. У всех есть удачные посты и неудачные.

Comment: А действительно,  почему я такие ситуации принимаю близко к сердцу? Наверное, со мной что-то не так. Я задумалась. Может быть, я «инопланетянка» какая, да только откуда мне это знать.  Потом вспомнила про дуэли во времена Пушкина. Вот, к примеру, смотрели крестьяне на своих дворян и думали: «Балуют, однако, господа!»  Сейчас они бы сказали, что «слишком эмоционально реагируют».

Comment: Впрочем, более образованные разночинцы тоже не воспринимали идею «дворянской чести», особенно в русском исполнении, хотя вот Базаров дрался на дуэли. Да и правительство такие «затеи» не одобряло, наказывала участников всяческим образом. Вот такие мысли…

Comment: @Sharon я не готов обсуждать Пушкина и «дворянскую честь», поэтому не могу ничего добавить к уже сказанному.

Comment: Конечно же, мы не будем всё это обсуждать, я просто объяснила Вам, почему лично мне не нравится голосование втайне, исподтишка. Сказать в открытую, не прячась - вот это честный поступок. Но это всё вопросы этики в субъективном изложении, а  их обсуждать здесь действительно неуместно. Все же ОБЪЕКТИВНЫЕ причины считать тайное голосование  НЕПРАВИЛЬНЫМ я уже изложила выше. Вы, как я полагаю, их таковыми не считаете. В любом случае спасибо Вам за разъяснение Вашей позиции, с большим и очень искренним к Вам уважением

Comment: @Sharon,  минусы ставят здесь пару человек из вредности или потому, что их ответ расходится с их ответом. Вот и все.  И что самое забавное: в их ответах содержится какое-то непонятное рассуждения.  Так правильно, потому что я так считаю. Вот и все.

Comment: А ставить минусы опытным участникам - глупо.